# Sed delimiter options

Tags: sed, delimiter

In my code, I need to replace variable assignments with addresses:

```
sed -i "s/^variable = .*$/variable = http://myaddress/"
```

Obviously, this does not work because the forward slashes in the address are recognized in the sed command.

I want to keep the `$` at the end of the first expression for replacing anything to the end of the line. I also do not want to escape the dollar sign as such, `\$` because it will search for a dollar sign.

Also, I don't want to just escape the forward slashes in the address as there are also variables in some places for the addresses.

I've tried using `#` instead of `/` but have to include what I don't want to - the `\$`.

Are there any alternate delimiters I can use that fit my situation?

Comment: Use single quotes, not double quotes, around the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` is interpreted by your shell. Wrap the whole argument to sed with `'` to prevent this.

```
sed -i 's#^variable = .*$#variable = http://myaddress#'
```

Comment: The greedy nature of `.*` should make the `$` superfluous, it will match to the end of the line anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i "s@^variable = .*$@variable = http://myaddress@" file
```

should work for you.

Note that the `$` in the first expression is not literature "dollar", but a regex expression, means, the end of the line.

Comment: sed -i "s@^variable = .*$@variable = http://${ENV_VAR}@" file still views the $@ in the middle as a variable..?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's#^variable = .*#variable = http://myaddress#'
```